# Why git pull for specific folder doesn't work? Which one is better alternative fetch/merge for git pull remote in this case?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm currently unable to find a substitute for `$ git pull origin /path/to/dir/or/file`. And apart of this I've tried these two steps but no luck.

1. `git fetch origin`
2. `git checkout HEAD /path/to/dir/`

In this manner I've fetched the whole directory but while checking out the repo/branch it doesn't do anything. Why? I'm concerned about this because I simply don't want to pull the whole repository.

Comment: With doing `git checkout HEAD` you are checking out the current commit, so the result is correct. You have to check out the fetched branch (maybe `origin/master`?) like this `git checkout origin/<branch> -- /path/to/dir`.

Comment: I can provide a more detailed answer, if you want me to.

Comment: Got it @Zeeker. I guess i wasn't mentioning the <branch> part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to *merge* (and not just replace a file), you need [`git checkout -m`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).
As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754938/why-git-pull-for-specific-folder-doesnt-work-which-one-is-better-alternative-f#comment38408543_24754938) by [Zeeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274224/zeeker), it needs to checkout a file from the branch you fetched, which is in the '`origin`' namespace.

```
git checkout -m origin/master -- /path/to/fileordir
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC. This solution works well. I think i need to brush up my git skills.